# get ngPrime working for Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, font-awesome

I already work on an Angular 2 project and so far GMap and Chartjs works.

But now i have the problem that if i include an Accordeon it doesn't get formatted properly.

I included primeng and primeui via

npm install primeng --save

npm install primeui --save

and also font-awesome via

npm install font-awesome --save

this is my angular-cli.json

```
    "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
            "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
            "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css"
          ],
    "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"
          ],
```

and this is the resulting output so far.

[resulting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ3R6.png)

It would be nice if anyone could bring up some suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by my self after a hard research ;-)

The solution is to import the .css files in the global styles.css and not in angular-cli.json

This is my new styles.css-file

```
    /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
    @import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css');
    @import url('../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css');
    @import url('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

[And this is my new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLere.png)

So maybe, if someone has the same fault this will help.